# How can I configure my Webpack file in Storybook correctly to compile my CSS with PostCSS?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, postcss, storybook

I have a Vue CLI up and running successfully with PostCSS and all of the plugins I require. However, when it comes to setting up the same PostCSS config for Storybook, no matter which combination of things I try from various sources that I've come across, I cannot get my Webpack file to compile correctly.

**.storybook/postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {},
        'postcss-nested': {},
        'postcss-custom-media': {},
        'postcss-advanced-variables': {},
    },
};
```

**.storybook/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
            'postcss-loader',
        ],
    });

    config.resolve.alias['@'] = rootPath;

    return config;
};
```

**./storybook.config.js**

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import '../src/css/main.css';
import '../src/stories/main.css';

Vue.use(Vuex);

function loadStories() {
    require('../src/stories');
}
configure(loadStories, module);
```

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./src/css/main.css (./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./src/css/main.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(2:1) Unknown word

  1 | 
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--6-1!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!./main.css");
    | ^
```

Comment: The issue is most likely that storybook already used a css loader and you are defining a second one that interferes with the build process. If you have multiple rulesets that process the same files you will encounter errors with webpacks. What you can do is search the existing rules for all rules that match `.css`, remove them from the rules array, and then add your own `.css` rule.